# Fetch query from Magento database -- mysql_num_rows

Tags: database, magento, fetch, mysql-num-rows

What function is equal to mysql_num_rows in Magento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Magento, the proper equivalent is PHP's [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

#### Why?

Magento usually uses `Varien_Data_Collection` instances to fetch result sets containing multiple records. Varien implements the [Lazy Load Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html) for these collections, that is, no result set will be fetched before you really need it.

If you take a look at the `Varien_Data_Collection` class, you'll see, that this class does implement PHP's [Countable interface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) and the proper `count()` method for this interface:

```
class Varien_Data_Collection implements IteratorAggregate, Countable
{
    :
    public function count()
    {
        $this->load();
        return count($this->_items);
    }
    :
}
```

If you're asking yourself now, what got lazy loading to do with counting records, then you need to know that querying a collection the usual Magento way, e.g. like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter(
        'status',
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED
    );
```

does *not* fetch the result set at all. But, how do you count records of a result set which hasn't been fetched yet? Right, you can't. And neither can `mysql_num_rows`. It fetches the result set first.

Now, when you call `count()` on the collection, e.g. by

```
$n = count($collection);
```

PHP's core `count()` function will detect that the passed argument `$collection` implements a `Countable` interface and has its own `count()` method defined, so it will call that one.

This leads to really fetching the result set<sup>*</sup> and storing it to `$this->_items`, which finally allows counting the records and return the number.

---

<sub>* In Magento you can also call `foreach ($collection as $product)` to really fetch the result set, but that's another story.</sub>